# make theme wmpl ready wpml-config

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, multilingual

I'm using the trego theme. As theme options you can set and change texts that will appear in the site (like e.g. texts for "copyright text" and "logo url"). How can I make this multilingual with WPML? i want make that by wpml-config.xml file

the code example in functions.options.php

```
        $of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Header",
                                "type"      => "heading"
        );

        $of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Logo",
                                "desc"      => "Upload logo here.",
                                "id"        => "site_logo",
                                "std"       => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png',
                                "type"      => "media"
        );

        $of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Logo (only Gallery Template)",
                                "desc"      => "Upload logo here.",
                                "id"        => "site_logo2",
                                "std"       => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png',
                                "type"      => "media"
        );
```

and this my try in wpml-config.xml (but not work)

```
    <wpml-config>

        <admin-texts>
            <key name="of_options">
                <key name="site_logo" />
                <key name="site_logo2" />
                <key name="copyright">
                </key>

        </admin-texts>
    </wpml-config>
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanx @kkarpieszuk 
i was resolved it by searching in my sql about site_logo and i found it in WP-options in option_name i found key that of_options store data in it

[image]
and right wpml-config.xml:

```
<wpml-config>
<admin-texts>
            <key name="theme_mods_trego">
            <key name="site_logo" />
            <key name="site_logo2" /> 
        </key>
    </key>

</admin-texts>
</wpml-config>
```

it work like charm

Comment: i see you have syntax error in your xml here. too much `</key>`. one will be enough :)

Answer (score 3):

here's Konrad from WPML dev/comp team :)

First,you need tohave strings ready for internationalisation. So do not use `"Logo"` but `__("Logo", "yourthemedomain");`

Then... well it depends how do you save your options. Does `$of_options` goes directly to `update_option('of_options', $of_options);`? If yes, you are quite ready. If not, rewrite it to be so.

Oh, I see your `$of_options` are actually three arrays. So xml shoul look like:

```
<wpml-config>

    <admin-texts>
        <key name="of_options">
            <key name="1">
             <key name="id" />
            </key>
        </key>

    </admin-texts>
</wpml-config>
```

So use indexes of inner arrays (name=1 in this case) and do not use values (logo_name) but their indexes (logo_name has array index `id`)